# Subqueries for PostgreSQL returns syntax error near select

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-insert

I am a beginner to database, and I am trying to run a subquery to insert data from one table to another one with identical schema.

```sql
insert into tbl_technologies_used (t_name_tech, t_category_tech, i_rating) 
  values (
    select t_name_tech, t_category_tech, i_rating 
    from tbl_technologies_proposed
  );
```

But I got this error:

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "select"
LINE 1: ... (t_name_tech, t_category_tech, i_rating) values (select t_n...
```

How can I fix this issue? I have checked my code again and again, but I can't find out the error.

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but you might want to read this: [Is adding the ‘tbl’ prefix to table names really a problem?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/154251/)

Comment: I was only copying this from a tutorial, but this is appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the source of an INSERT is a SELECT, you can't use `VALUES`:

```
insert into tbl_technologies_used (t_name_tech, t_category_tech, i_rating) 
select t_name_tech, t_category_tech, i_rating 
from tbl_technologies_proposed
```

The `values` clause provides a static set of rows which is not needed as the rows to be inserted come from your SELECT statement.

Comment: What does a static set of rows mean? Is there any keyword I can use for that behavior of `values`?

Comment: `values (1,2), (3,4)` is a static set of two rows with two columns